# How to disable an element from a selectOneMenu if it selected once?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have integrated a search with JSF inside a view. This search has 2 search boxes and 2 search filters. The 2 filters contain the same elements. THis is done so the user can make search combinations. If the user wants to search he gives the input and clicks the search button. The search button executes a javascript function that makes API calls and takes the right data. What I want to do is prevent the user from selecting the same filter element on both of filters(For example if in the first filter "name" is chosen, this cannot be chosen at the second filter). I have tried something with itemDisabled but no luck until now...

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You should show only one list with multi select and let user choose only 2 from them

Comment: Can it be done with 2 filters?

Comment: Yes it can be done with 2 filter but it will require handling for syncing selected values

Comment: Can you please give me more information

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic #1

Comment: I read it. Now what?